# Excel autofill a column with 76000+ rows not working

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a column to print a different text based on the cell color of another cell. So for example, A1 color is green, and A2 is red. So I want B1 and B2 to be "new" and "old", respectively.

My approach is to first create a function to get the color using the below function:

```
Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
    ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Using `=ColorIndex(A1)', this works great because for it prints a 4 and for red it prints a 3. I can intern use IF to print "old" and "new".

I run into an issue when I try to auto fill the rest of the column with the same formula. Basically I want to use =ColorIndex() for all 76000 rows in column B. I tried double clicking the drag handle and manually selecting Fill, but nothing happened. Any one know why this is happening and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Nothing at all happened?  Can you drag it down a shorter distance and does it work then?

Comment: **1.** `I tried double clicking the drag handle and manually selecting Fill, but nothing happened. ` Till the time there is data in Col A, B or C till 76000 rows, the `double clicking` will work. If there is no data then you will have to manually drag it down to 76000th row. **2.** Also Having that formula down to 76000 will make Excel slow.  When you double click, your Excel will hang for sometime while it calculates all 76000 rows.

Comment: @TimWilliams Nothing happened at all. I can drag it manually and it does work but I am trying to see if there is shorter way to do it instead of dragging it for one minute

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes there is data in A. I even tried putting in the formula in row 75900 and double click to autofill so it only fills 100 rows, still nothing happens

Comment: Click on `File Tab | Options | Advanced`. Check if the `Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop` checkbox is checked.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yep its checked. Still nothing, it doesn't even show it's running. Maybe there's a limit on how many rows I can do autofill? :/

Comment: If this is not part of other macro and the only need is to populate cells with "new" or "Old" in the next column ... If after selecting the column, you can use find colored cells using Find Format (Control+F), then use find all and press control+A to select the cells with the color in that column. Then after pressing esc (escaping find dialogue box), you have the selected cells with that color in that column. You can then run a macro to offset the selected range by 1 column and value them with "New" or "Old" as desired. This will be ***faster than formula***, I think.

Comment: The only thing I can think to add is `Ctrl+d` to pull down for manual entry without a mouse, or using a script to `range().formula = "=colorindex()" for a more dynamic entry.  If it can't work via automation, then there may be an underlying issue.